# Stream content of txt file in real time to rails view

Tags: ruby, file-io

What would be the simplest approach to streaming the contents of a file to the web page, as it gets updated.

I currently have a `.txt` file that is constantly updated while a script is running, and I want to display that on the page for the users as it is updated.

Is there a simple gem or technology out there to accomplish this? Or is there an excellent pure Ruby approach?

My first thought was to use some kind of AJAX request to return diffs of the file, but I feel that would be a bad approach.

Comment: humm,do you want to update the webpage form fields values from the .txt files?

Comment: I don't have a form, right now just a simple div. And I would like it to always contain the information from the file, even if it changes. Let me know if I can provide further information.

Comment: Okay! but you want to update a webpage you told,right?

Comment: Yes, I would like the web page to be updated on the fly.

Comment: okie is the source file is .txt file ? or it could be changed to .xlsx file also?

Comment: Preferrably some text format. Right now I am outputting STDOUT of a system call into a `.txt` file. Excel might make things more challenging.

Comment: I can give you an algorithm,will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Celluloid's Reel by Tony Arcieri](https://github.com/celluloid/reel) to accomplish this.

I run this in the background (received a lot of help from [Adam Dalton](https://twitter.com/fladamd) on this part):

**my_reel.rb**

```
require 'reel'

CONNECTIONS = []
Reel::Server.supervise("0.0.0.0", 5000) do |connection|
 while request = connection.request
   case request
     when Reel::Request
       puts "Client requested: #{request.method} #{request.url} #{request.body}"
       CONNECTIONS.each do |c|
         c << request.body
       end
       request.respond :ok, 'YES! YOU GOT IT!'
     when Reel::WebSocket
       puts "Client made a WebSocket request to: #{request.url}"
       CONNECTIONS << request
       break
   end
 end
end

sleep
```

Then I wrote a command line script to send post requests to the Reel server. Had a lot of help from [Writing Ruby Scripts That Respect Pipelines by Jesse Storimer](http://www.jstorimer.com/2011/12/12/writing-ruby-scripts-that-respect-pipelines.html).

**~/bin/serve_it_up**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'httparty'

ARGF.each_line do |line|
  output_line = line.chop
  HTTParty.post 'http://localhost:5000', body: output_line                                                                                                                                   
end
```

Then to make it work, my Rails application uses Sidekiq (`bundle exec sidekiq`), and runs a script in the background when a button is clicked, which sends the output to a file, `output.txt`. So I run a forced tail and pipe it's output to my command line script.

```
tail -f output.txt | serve_it_up
```

In my web app, I have some JavaScript (CoffeeScript in this case) that hooks up to the web socket and puts the output on the page:

```
connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:5000')

connection.onmessage = (event) ->
  $('#prompt').append(event.data + '<br/>')
  prompt = document.getElementById('prompt')
  prompt.scrollTop = prompt.scrollHeight
```

So anytime that output.txt changes, it'll take the output from `tail -f` and put it in the web browser. I also style the `#prompt` div to have a limited height, and I keep it always scrolled to the bottom.

Here is the style for it:

```
#prompt {
  font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using something like Faye or the gem [private_pub](https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub) (it makes Faye channels private) which allows you to make use of web sockets or long polling to push new data to the client. There is a lot of documentation on the Github page and also a RailsCast.

In your app or script you could then publish to the server which will push the new data to all subscribed channels.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll take a look and update you on the results as I have it.

Comment: @ardavis How did you get on with this?